# Как избежать конфликта заголовочных файлов ?

Tags: include, c++

Есть у меня `main.cpp` в котором имеется

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "tools.h"
```

, и есть `tools.h`, в котором тоже есть #include `<windows.h>`.

Естественно это вызывает конфликт. Как его избежать, оставив в обоих файлах `#include <windows.h>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tools.h

```
#ifndef _WINDOWS_
#include <windows.h>
#endif
```

но вообще тот сорс, в котором я это увидел, говорит о том, что это и есть include guard и второй раз подключать `windows.h` вполне безопасно

Comment: @Etki откуда _WINDOWS_ ? что это и где об этом почитать?

Comment: @ололо, так, а что за windows.h вообще? ) их, оказывается, несколько.

Comment: @Etki я имею в виду то что стоит после @ifndef

Comment: @ололо, в windows.h (по крайней мере в том, который идет с MinGW) есть вот это:

    #ifndef _WINDOWS_H
    #define _WINDOWS_H
    
    ...
    
    #endif

Весь код обернут в этот ifndef, так что, сколько windows.h не подключай, конфликта не будет.

Comment: @ололо, это называется include guard - константа (ну, не совсем, я плаваю в терминологии), которая задается при первом подключении файла. Весь код файла обернут в аналогичный `#ifndef`, что позволяет избежать повторного процессинга содержимого этого `#ifndef` компилятором

Comment: Возьмите за правило всегда оборачивать содержимого любого .h файла в уникальный guard.

    // tools.h
    #ifndef _TOOLS_H
    #define _TOOLS_H
    ... содержимое файла
    #endif

Для примера можете почитать файлы из `/usr/include/`